# Partial Index on Postgres where condition is in separate table

Tags: postgresql, partial-index

I have table schema as:

```
table_a:
    id
    active boolean
 
table_b:
    id
    table_a_id ForeignKey
```

I want to apply a partial unique index on table_b but only if active=True for table_a_id.

Is this feasible in postgres?

Comment: I don't think that you want to create an index on another table will be worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html):

> The expression used in the WHERE clause can refer only to columns of
> the **underlying** table, but it can use all columns, not just the ones
> being indexed.